# Redirect on rowSelection with JQGrid in grails

Tags: grails, redirect, jqgrid, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am using the plugin JQGrid 3.8.0.1 on a Grails Project having the Grails 2.0.3 version.

I have this `<jqgrid:grid>` having an attribute `onSelectRow`. I was planning to convert my redirect structure from the form structure to window structure. The reason for doing this conversion is that not all `.gsp` files having a JQGrid component have a `<form>` component in the `<body>` area.

From this:

```
<jq:resources/>
<jqui:resources/>
<jqgrid:resources/>
<jqgrid:grid
// other main attributes (i.e., url, colNames, colModel, etc.)
onSelectRow="function(id) {
    document.<formname>.action = 'view/' + id;
    document.<formname>.submit();
}"></jqgrid:grid>

// html body content of form
<form name="<formname>">
</form>
```

To this:

```
<jq:resources/>
<jqui:resources/>
<jqgrid:resources/>
<jqgrid:grid
// other main attributes (i.e., url, colNames, colModel, etc.)
onSelectRow ="function(id) {
    window.location.href = ${createLink(action:'show', id:id)};
}"></jqgrid:grid>
```

> The `jq`, `jqui`, `jqgrid` tags are the plugins installed on the project by the grails command `grails> install-plugin jquery jquery-ui jqgrid`

The problem is the new script won't work. Upon checking the new html source code returns the value of `onSelectRow` attribute `window.location.href = /<Project Name>/<Controller>/show;`. The question is how can I have the JQGrid running properly on the new script.

> Note: I am currently using the scaffold functionality of Grails or `generate-all *` command

Comment: you need to define controller name in createLink function.

Comment: Still not working. Even the controller isn't defined, Grails will return a default controller name where the page is currently packaged or located in the `grails-app/view` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onSelectRow: function(id,status)
{
     //var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(id); 
}
```

try to replace `'='` with `':'` and try.

Comment: I can't replace `=` with `:`. I'm am using the JQGrid on Grails by JQGridTagLib, `<jqgrid:grid>`. Can you supply the code by the format given above? Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my codes with the necessary adjustments. Only the `onSelectRow` would be my concern, other attributes are working as it should be after page load.